# Cordova error when building Android platform

Tags: android, extjs, ant, cordova

I have a brand new Cordova app with iOS and Android platforms, iOS is building fine but building for Android is returning the error below.

```
[Error: An error occurred while building the android project.Error executing "ant clean -f /path/to/file/build.xml": Build failed]
```

The build.xml file does exist and the Android developer tools are installed. I am not sure if it's a conf issue or an issue with Ant. I am on Mac OS 10.8.5.

Comment: I ran the command with sudo and received another error saying that JAVA_HOME wasn't set which led me to this post, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5422. I patched the file in question which resolved that particular issue but now I am right back to where I started.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was due to spaces in my file path.